# Why does this users does not need PAM two factor Authentication for logging in?

Tags: ssh, login, authentication, pam, two-factor-authentication

I inherited a system from a departed colleague. He setup two factor authentication on the system, except for user `root` and `ftpupload`.

However, there is this particular user who has SSH access but does not need two factor authentication.
This user can just login with username and password!

I notice he setup that any users in the group `disable2fa` do require two factor authentication. I only see the following users in this group:

```
$ getent group disable2fa
disable2fa:x:2003:root,publicftpupload
```

I have checked the PAM file (`sudo nano /etc/pam.d/sshd`) and I see the following:

```
# PAM configuration for the Secure Shell service

# Standard Un*x authentication.
@include common-auth

# Disallow non-root logins when /etc/nologin exists.
account    required     pam_nologin.so

# Uncomment and edit /etc/security/access.conf if you need to set complex
# access limits that are hard to express in sshd_config.
# account  required     pam_access.so

# Standard Un*x authorization.
@include common-account

# SELinux needs to be the first session rule.  This ensures that any
# lingering context has been cleared.  Without this it is possible that a
# module could execute code in the wrong domain.
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so close

# Set the loginuid process attribute.
session    required     pam_loginuid.so

# Create a new session keyring.
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke

# Standard Un*x session setup and teardown.
@include common-session

# Print the message of the day upon successful login.
# This includes a dynamically generated part from /run/motd.dynamic
# and a static (admin-editable) part from /etc/motd.
session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
session    optional     pam_motd.so noupdate

# Print the status of the user's mailbox upon successful login.
session    optional     pam_mail.so standard noenv # [1]

# Set up user limits from /etc/security/limits.conf.
session    required     pam_limits.so

# Read environment variables from /etc/environment and
# /etc/security/pam_env.conf.
session    required     pam_env.so # [1]
# In Debian 4.0 (etch), locale-related environment variables were moved to
# /etc/default/locale, so read that as well.
session    required     pam_env.so user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale

# SELinux needs to intervene at login time to ensure that the process starts
# in the proper default security context.  Only sessions which are intended
# to run in the user's context should be run after this.
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so open

# Standard Un*x password updating.
@include common-password
auth [success=done default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup disable2fa
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok
```

Is there anywhere else I need to check? Can anybody help? Thanks!

Comment: Since you mention SSH specifically, are there any `Match User` directives in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` that might be relevant?

Answer (score 0):

That's what this line does:

```
auth [success=done default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup disable2fa
```

From [`man pam.d`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/pam.d.5.html):

```
ok
   this tells PAM that the administrator thinks this return code should contribute
   directly to the return code of the full stack of modules. In other words, if the
   former state of the stack would lead to a return of PAM_SUCCESS, the module's return
   code will override this value. Note, if the former state of the stack holds some value
   that is indicative of a modules failure, this 'ok' value will not be used to override
   that value.

done
   equivalent to ok with the side effect of terminating the module stack and PAM
   immediately returning to the application.
```

Essentially `success=done` means that if this module succeeds, nothing more needs to be checked, so the subsequent `pam_google_authenticator.so` is skipped if this module succeeds, and this module just checks if [the user is the group `disable2fa`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/pam_succeed_if.8.html):

```
user ingroup group
   User is in given group.
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear. Problem is the problematic user is **not** in the 'disable2fa' group. Other users are being prompted with PAM tfa

Comment: @user1034912 are you sure about that? It might be their primary group.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably deconfigure the "user ingroup disable2fa" lines in your PAM configuration files and replace them with the setup that's documented in:

https://codeberg.org/kpiq/Tech-Space/wiki/2FA-Authenticator-app-%28any-compatible-with-Google-Authenticator%29-setup-for-Ubuntu-Jammy

That way only the users that have configured their Google Authenticator tokens (~/.google_authenticator file) will get asked for a verification code.  The "user ingroup" setup was a question mark for me until I found the nullok argument in the documentation.

It works like a charm!